# C++ specialization needs opening namespace

Tags: c++

Template specialization in C++ requires the opening of the library namespace. As far as I'm aware, this is considered bad programming technique. For example the widely used `YAML-CPP` library uses this technique for type conversion. See [YAML-CPP convert<> template](https://codedocs.xyz/jbeder/yaml-cpp/convert_8h_source.html).

Their declaration:

```
namespace YAML {
template <typename T>
struct convert;
}
```

Possible definition:

```
namespace YAML {
struct convert<MyOwnType> {
  MyOwnType convert() {
    return MyOwnType{};
  }
}
}
```

Is there a better C++ construct to create a type conversion functionality without having to open a namespace, etc of a library?

Comment: *As far as I'm aware, this is considered bad programming technique* Not really.  It's standard practice in the standard library to open the namespace to put specializations in for your own types.

Comment: what do you mean with "open a namespace" ? You refer to `namespace x{ ...something... }` and then later `namespace x{ ... something else... }` ? Thats basically what namespaces are good for ;)

Comment: The question here is rather whether the library author intends/allows you to add specializations. If they do, then there is no problem with the shown code. If they don't then trying it is pointless in the first place.

Comment: https://tio.run/##dY5Bi8JADIXv8yseeHD34B@wtbB3xYuXhYUyxCgFmxmmGRcp89u7MyJWFjwlee8lX8j71ZloWnRCl3hk1J0bNLDtG2PE9jx4S4zvr90Wo1Hu/cVqTunNc7FxaEzOR1KQkysHrUwy00Pa3fa/cshRjC/9x2ceBz2u1@Sioq7Rtqco1LalX/7IskJCqswL70kpn5TFO6t@Hm3yd4DzHKy68A@WHSCwxiCzM2YAkEwuUyeK3nYyp99iqLr7M0CxKWKa/gA